# Unexpected token export jest angular

Tags: angular, jestjs

I read a lot of posts about this problem but I didn't understand how to fix it. I tried many solutions and I have still an error.

```
 Details:

    /home/work/project/node_modules/ngx-cookie-service/index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export * from './cookie-service/cookie.service';
                                                                                             ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

      15 |         this.sessionStorage = sessionStorage;
      16 |         this.localStorage = localStorageService;
    > 17 |         this.cookieService = cookieService;
         |                              ^
      18 |     }
      19 |
      20 |     public set(key, value, useSessionStorage = true) {

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:403:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/myApp/coreModule/services/storageLayer.service.ts:17:30)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/myApp/itemModule/components/category.component.ts:30:32)
```

So I added this to my package.json :

```
  "jest": {
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!ngx-cookie-service)"
    ]
  }
```

The problem is still there. Anybody can help ? Should I use "moduleNameMapper" to mock ngx-cookie-service ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

I added

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
  "node_modules/(?!@ngrx|ngx-cookie-service|ng-dynamic)"
],
```

to package.json and that fixed the issue.

When I remove `ng-dynamic` from the regex the tests fail with the same execption. I have no idea why but they shouldn't, imo, since I don't have that module.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a solution to this problem.

1. add a folder `__mocks__` in root folder where the node_modules reside.
2. add `ngx-cookie-service.js` file in `__mocks__` folder and place the following code:

```
class MockCookieService {
  constructor() {
    this._cookieReg = {};
  }
  check(name) {
    return this._cookieReg[name] ? true : false;
  }
  get(name) {
    return this._cookieReg[name];
  }
  getAll() {
    return this._cookieReg;
  }
  set(
    name,
    value,
    expires,
    path,
    domain,
    secure,
    sameSite
  ) {
    this._cookieReg[name] = name + '=' + value;
  }
  delete(name, path, domain) {
    delete this._cookieReg[name];
  }
  deleteAll(path, domain) {
    this._cookieReg = {};
  }
}

module.exports = {
  CookieService: MockCookieService
};
```

3. now in actual component spec file, place the following code:

```
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
jest.genMockFromModule('ngx-cookie-service');
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [Your-Component],
  providers: [CookieService]
})
```

4. now run `jest` the tests will run fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the same approach `transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/?!@angular']` in `jest.config.js` file and worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).